# nmap and print(nm.csv()) help needed to print out to csv.file

Tags: python, csv, nmap

I need you help with nmap script and printing the output to csv file.
When I run the script and finish it with `print(nm.csv())` I got the following results displayed which is what I want first place:

```
host;hostname;hostname_type;protocol;port;name;state;product;extrainfo;reason;version;conf;cpe
82.214.228.176;176.228.214.82.in-addr.arpa;PTR;tcp;21;ftp;open;;;syn-ack;;3;
82.214.228.176;176.228.214.82.in-addr.arpa;PTR;tcp;22;ssh;open;;;syn-ack;;3;
82.214.228.176;176.228.214.82.in-addr.arpa;PTR;tcp;53;domain;open;;;syn-ack;;3;
82.214.228.176;176.228.214.82.in-addr.arpa;PTR;tcp;80;http;open;;;syn-ack;;3;
```

But my question is how to get this redirected or to create a csv file on the same Directory from where I run the script or maybe in a path.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could declare a function like this one

```
def save_csv_data(nm_csv, path='.'):
    with open(path + '/output.csv', 'w') as output:
        output.write(nm_csv)
```

then by passing an argument you could specify another path to save the file, or otherwise, use the same directory as the script:

```
if (len(sys.argv) > 1 and sys.argv[1]):
    save_csv_data(nm.csv(), path=sys.argv[1])
else:
    save_csv_data(nm.csv())
```

**Edit:** also remember to `import sys`

I also would suggest you, if you decide to use arguments, use a module like [argparse](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html).

Comment: Thank you Martin!

Comment: I got it! :) Thank you so much Martin!

Comment: @IvanMadolev could you add more code to your question? Maybe it can help to solve your problem, thank you!

Comment: you're welcome! You can accept the answer if you think this solution works for you! :) Also kudos to @SmartManoj as his solution is valid to print the information to a file.

Comment: Use the function should add output.close() in the function,if not,the connection could not be closed easily.

Comment: this solution did not work for me, as my CSV is comming out with ;; and some times ;;;

Answer (score 1):

```
print (nm.csv(),file=open('a.csv','w'))
```

**Edited**:

You can use the print_function to get the print() behaviour from python3 in python2:

```
from __future__ import print_function
```

Comment: Hey Smart, i am getting syntax error:                                                                             File "test2.py", line 22
    print (nm.csv(),file=open('a.csv','w'))
                        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax